# SIGSEGV Infinite Function Loop

Tags: bash

below is some bash code I have written that is tasked with searching through a directory given as a command line argument. It will go though and concatenate files of the .sh extension, ignore any other files, but if there is a directory it will search that directory too.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0

function search() {
    for x in $1; do
        if [ "$x" == "*.sh" ]; then
            'let counter++'     
            echo "$x":
            cat "$x"
        elif [[ -d "$x" ]]; then
            search "$1";
        fi
    done 
}

search "$1"

if [ $counter -eq 0 ]; then
  echo No files
fi
```

When I run the bash script I get a `SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault` with code 11. Research makes me think it is due to an infinite loop with my function but I don't know where I could be looping infinitely.

I've ran my code through ShellCheck and no issues are detected, I've looked at syntax for using functions and I think I am the function correctly and I am actually just lost as to why I have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are recursing on $1 where you should be using $x. No wonder it's an infinite loop! There's some other errors, though.

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0

function search() {
    cd "$1"
    for x in *; do
        if [[ "$x" = *.sh ]]; then
            let counter++
            echo "$x":
            # cat "$x"
        elif [ -d "$x" ]; then
            search "$x";
        fi
    done
    cd ".."
}

search "$1"
echo $counter files found
```

So you need to for-loop through * (all files) in order to see the directories. And you need to use [[ ]] for pattern matching, and the pattern can't be in quotes. Also note how we cd down into the directories and back up again. And the let command shouldn't have been in quotes.